# How to I get access to all of my friends about me

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I was just curious if there was a way to use the graph api to get all of a user's friends about me similar to line of code?

```
$friends = $facebook->api("/me/friends");
```

but instead of just returning the friend's Name and ID it would nice to returns there "about me" as well. If i'm going to need to use a fql query instead, please post it in the answers section. Though, I would prefer a graph call if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve additional fields of Users by specifying them explicitly along with the end point, for example instead of

```
/me/friends
```

You can use the following with `friends_about_me` permission to retrieve the `bio`

```
/me/friends?fields=name,id,bio
```

Comment: thx is there a page somewhere on the facebook documentation that I missed that shows examples of this type of syntax?

Comment: You can look at [Field Expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/)

Comment: Man i saw that page before i guess i never connected the dots.